# How to equally split the results of MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say I write a SELECT statement in MYSQL(version MySQL 8.0) which fetches "n" records.
I want this "n" records be split approximately equally by 3 and additionally need to make sure that 10% of these n records are shared by the 3 parts that it was divided into.

Is it possible to do this in the select statement itself or do I need to write a function to perform this operation.

Example:
My select query fetches as below:

```
ID Name Age
1  ABC  22
2  XYZ  23
3  awe  22
4  wer  23
5  per  23
6  mnm  24
7  lmk  23
8  uyt  22
9  prt  23
10 ler  26
```

I now need it split into let's say 3 and 10% should be shared by the 3 parts that it has been split to (since it's 10 records, in this example 1 record should be shared by the three sets)

```
Set 1:
1  ABC  22
2  XYZ  23
3  awe  22
4  wer  23
Set 2:
4  wer  23
5  per  23
6  mnm  24
7  lmk  23
Set 3:
4  wer  23
8  uyt  22
9  prt  23
10 ler  26
```

Comment: Are 3 users 3 different database connections? Is the number of records fixed at 1000? What have you tried? Which MySQL version?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something SQL could do easily. It's should be easier in a client programming language.

Comment: Once you find out how many records there are, you can use `LIMIT offset, length` to specify the range of records in each set.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to do this in the client. My gut tells me that the requirements are apt to change, so it's better to use SQL to just get the whole dataset, and then you should write code to sort them into your three subsets (or whatever) by whatever rules you want.

Comment: Show examples with non-multiples of 10 records.  How does the 10% round?  Do you have sets with different numbers of records?  If not, what do you do?

Comment: Is "n" the number of records in the table?  If not, what determines which get picked?

Comment: You say split it into "let's say" 3.  Is that dependent on the data?  What range of possible numbers of sets is there?